# ¿Cómo inicializar un arreglo con parámetro generico T?

Tags: java, genéricos

¿Cómo hago para inicializar un objeto de tipo T (parámetro genérico de clase).

```
public class Bolsa<T> {

    private int capacidad = 10;
    private int elementosActual;

    private T array;

    public Bolsa(int capacidad) {
        this.capacidad = capacidad;

        array = new T[10];//Error en tiempo de compilación.

    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se puede lograr eso en Java debido al type erasure (borrado de tipo). Tienes estas alternativas:

1. Pasar la clase de `T` como argumento en el constructor y crear el arreglo utilizando reflexión:

   ```
   public Bolsa(Class<T> clazz, int capacidad) {
       array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, capacidad);
   }
   ```

   El código cliente llamaría al constructor de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   Bolsa<String> bolsa = new Bolsa(String.class, 10);
   ```
2. Crear un arreglo de `Object` y hacer el casteo respectivo al momento de devolver elementos del arreglo (utilizada en la implementación de [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)):

   ```
   public class Bolsa<T> {
       Object[] arreglo;

       public Bolsa(int capacidad) {
           arreglo = new Object[capacidad];
       }

       public T obtener(int indice) {
           //agrega validaciones correspondientes
           return (T) arreglo[indice];
       }
   }
   ```
3. Utilizar un artificio basado en un arreglo de `Object`:

   ```
   arreglo = (T[]) new Object[capacidad];
   ```

La primera es la más segura en tiempo de desarrollo y ejecución. La segunda y tercera tienen el artificio de trabajar con un arreglo de objetos y utilizar un casteo hacia abajo del tipo particular que será borrado en tiempo de ejecución, pero apoya durante el trabajo en tiempo de desarrollo. Además, en la segunda y tercera opción, debes tener cuidado al exponer el arreglo directamente a los clientes puesto que podrían malograr la información que se guarda en él.

Comment: La primera no la entendí

Comment: El resto si, muchas gracias

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo para que se entienda la primera forma. Si aún tienes dudas, por favor coméntalas y trataré de responderlas hasta donde pueda. Igual siempre puedes encontrarme en el chat, me mandas un mensaje allí y conversamos.

Comment: Luiggi te envié un mail, sino te molesta hablamos por otro lado que tengo unas dudas de programación en general y no conozco a nadie que pueda respondérmelas

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos problemas con el código:

1. El objeto de nombre 'array' de tipo genérico `T` al que quiere asignarle el arreglo de 10 objetos de tipo `T` no es un arreglo, por lo tanto generará error de compilación al no poder hacer casting de un array a un objeto...
2. **¡Pero!**, así este objeto 'array' fuera de tipo arreglo, Java prohibe crear arreglos de tipo genérico. Es una cuestión de diseño y compatibilidad: un objeto de tipo genérico en tiempo de ejecución no sabe de qué clase es (por ejemplo, la clase `T` puede ser `Integer`, `Cow`, `God`, `Raccoon` o cualquier otra  que usted defina, pero esto nunca lo sabe porque en realidad `T` es un comodín para cualquiera). Por otro lado, los arreglos SÍ necesitan saber de qué tipo son sus elementos. Por lo tanto se impone esta restricción.

Debido a esto, en tiempo de ejecución hay que 'forzar' el conocimiento del tipo de clase, para eso puede usar un [método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int)) de la clase `Array` llamado `newInstance`. Este método recibe dos parámetros: un objeto de tipo `Class` también geneŕico que le permite al método saber en tiempo de ejecución a cuál clase hace referencia y dos, el tamaño del arreglo. Un ejemplo, intentando crear un arreglo de tipo `T` de 10 elementos:

```
T[] genericArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clase, 10);
```

donde la variable `clase` es de tipo `Class<T>`. La expresión `(T[])` sirve para realizar casting del tipo de objeto devuelto por este método (que en el Javadoc indica es de tipo Object) a un arreglo de tipo `T`, expresión que es segura por cuanto ya este arreglo conoce, en tiempo de ejecución, la clase a la que hace referencia.

Comment: Cuidado, tu variable no se puede llamar `class` porque es una palabra reservada en Java.

Comment: Ups, pequeño detalle.