# ¿Cómo inicializar arreglo genérico?

Tags: array, constructor, genericos, colecciones, inicializacion

debo desarrollar una colección personalizada, que contenga como atributo un arreglo de tipo genérico, y que esta clase contenga sus respectivo métodos(add, addfirst, etc.).
El problema lo encuentro que al armar el constructor inicializo con null el array y al instanciar los métodos y compilar, se rompe el programa.
¿Cómo inicializo arreglo?

package practica.semanal5;

public class CollectionCustom implements ManipularArray {

```
private T[] arrayT;
```

Comment: Debes declarar el genérico en la definición de la clase para poder utilizarlo como un tipo dentro de la clase. `class CollectionCustom<T> implements ManipularArray{}`.

Comment: En cuanto a la inicialización del array genérico, basta con algo como `private T[] arrayT = (T[]) new Object[5];`. Esto es por ejemplo, para inicializarlo en un arreglo de tamaño 5. ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo inicializar un arreglo con parámetro generico T?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4724/c%c3%b3mo-inicializar-un-arreglo-con-par%c3%a1metro-generico-t)

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo y respuesta, ceo que es por ahi.